# How to get the contacts which is only in firebase in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web, contacts

This is user collection

[image]

I want get contact and show to the user only the contacts which is in firebase like Whatsapp

[image: Reference image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you facing issue with reading from Firestore or with displaying content on Flutter? And you should paste minimum reproducible code so others can help you

Comment: No,i have done with getting all the contacts from device. And i have firestore collection for the user who have signed in.The collection contains the phone.Now what I want is to compare the whole contacts and display only the contact which is in my user collection.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent documentation for that in Firebase docs.

Check the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

Example for your collection can be

```
Firestore.instance.collection("users").get()
```

Remember its good practice to paginate large collection, from my perspective it seems your collection is going to be large. [Pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors)

Comment: Could you explain it more please, I'm new to it

Comment: This is not a forum :) Check the firebase docs, I think they are pretty intuitive and update your question

Comment: Kindly help me with this because i need to make this now , Please

Comment: Well, then tell me what you are fighting with?

Comment: @JohnDavidPrakash You need to "make this now", and then you don't answer to people who try to help you?

Comment: I have done with getting all the contact for device and i have made the collection for the users who have signed in . The collection collection contains phone number. Now I want to display only the contact number which is in my firebase collection

Comment: I'm very sorry for late reply